# PHP MP4 Streaming Not Working

Tags: php, streaming, mp4

I have a HTML page named calling.html in the a folder named 'Folder':

```
<html>
<body>
    <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="getvideo.php" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

The getvideo.php script I am using is calls a function to get the video file and generate a buffer stream:

```
<?php

getVideo();

function getVideo() {

    $file = '/home/sites/domain/protected/x.mp4';
    $fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');

    $size   = filesize($file); // File size
    $length = $size;           // Content length
    $start  = 0;               // Start byte
    $end    = $size - 1;       // End byte

    header('Content-type: video/mp4');
    //header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        $c_start = $start;
        $c_end   = $end;

        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range == '-') {
            $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
        }else{
            $range  = explode('-', $range);
            $c_start = $range[0];
            $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }
        $start  = $c_start;
        $end    = $c_end;
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
        fseek($fp, $start);
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    }
    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
    header("Content-Length: ".$length);

    $buffer = 1024 * 8;
    while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {

        if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
            $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
        }
        set_time_limit(0);
        echo fread($fp, $buffer);
        flush();
    }

    fclose($fp);
    exit();
}
?>
```

The problem that I have is that if I wrap the getVideo() function call in a if statement as follows, the video stops working on the HTML page (it works fine when removing the if statement around the function call):

```
$referer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if ($referer == '/Folder/calling.html') {
    getVideo();
}
```

Could someone please help, I can't seem to spot what the issue with this is?

Comment: Note: I have tested and ($referer == '/Folder/calling.html') is true

Answer (score 0):

Add an else statement to your if statement and see if you get a result.